# Боковое меню на андроид

Tags: меню, android, java

Всем добрый вечер.
Возник следующий вопрос!
До сегодняшнего дня боковое меню в моем приложении было организованно посредством виджета `SlidePaneLayout`, но меня данное решение не устраивало по ряду причин, поэтому немного погуглив нашел следующую [библиотеку](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) и [пример](http://android-helper.com.ua/slidingmenu/).
Повторил и все работает на отлично. Далее решил перенести все в свой проект, добаил кода и запустил а приложение при запуске крошится. В чем может быть проблема?

Ниже код и стектрейс. Говорит ошибка в указании `Context`, пробовал: `this, Main.this, getBaseContext()` - все равно ни в какую!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(Main.this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);

    // ///////////
    menu.attachToActivity(Main.this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    // //////////
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.leftmenu);

    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_btn_list_up);
    //mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    Drawable ab_res = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_back);
    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(ab_res);

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm == null) {
        System.out.println("Отсутствует соединение");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Отсутствует соединение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo == null) {
        System.out.println("Отсутствует соединение");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Отсутствует соединение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) 
    {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI") || ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")) {
            if (ni.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("Есть Internet");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Есть Интернет",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                getVersiondata();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Стектрейс:

```
>         09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866): FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.initCustomViewAbove(CustomViewAbove.java:167)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.<init>(CustomViewAbove.java:157)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.<init>(CustomViewAbove.java:152)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.<init>(SlidingMenu.java:207)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.<init>(SlidingMenu.java:190)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.<init>(SlidingMenu.java:169)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> com.melikovivan.yummy.Main.onCreate(Main.java:96)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>     09-30 13:54:44.559: E/AndroidRuntime(1866):   at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все всем спасибо! Вопрос снят. Нашел решение.
Просто поменял targetSDK на 18 с 17 и все заработало!
Не знаю в чем подвох, но работает! Одно из решений [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/194056/).